# Monitoring Multiple Amazon Account EC2 Instances

Tags: amazon-ec2

Our company had multiple Amazon cloud accounts. Now my question is i want to monitor all account EC2 instances using Amazon AWS management console.

Answer (score 0):

You can't... they all need to be on the same account for you to monitor them together with the AWS management console. I suggest using something like ElasticFox as it allows you to switch between accounts easily and has almost all the same functionality of the AWS Console. It lacks a few things like being able to assign permissions to AMI's and Volumes but for the most part it's pretty complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Xervmon. They provide multi cloud management, you can add as many Amazon cloud accounts as you want and manage, monitor them with ease. We have used up to 5 different Amazon Cloud Accounts so far and it works great.